# Simulating wave-speed in a spring under tension

Tags: classical-mechanics, computational-physics, simulations

I'm wondering, in a simulation of a one-dimensional spring, how do you accurately model wave-speed?

I'm working on a problem like this, and my approach was to break the string into many segments. At each time-step, I used hooke's law to calculate forces on each intersection, and move it accordingly.

The problem is, that means that the time it takes for the signal to travel from point A to point B isn't proportional to the mass/tension, it's proportional to the number of segments. That's an artifact of the simulation, not a physical property!

How do people get around this? I could imagine tuning the length of each segment as one possible solution.

And, same question but in three dimensions. Is it just carefully tuning the size of the finite elements?

**Edit:** An explanation of how signal-time depends on number of segments separating two points:

Imagine I have A connected to D by 3 line segments (A-B-C-D) under tension, and at equilibrium. If I displace A at t=0, then AB will be compressed, and B will feel a force. At t=1, B will have moved, and now C will feel a force. At t=2, C will move, and at t=3, D will move.

If I doubled the number of internal nodes, it would take twice as many timesteps for the signal to go from one end to the other. Moreover, it's independent of the tension, only of the number of mesh-points.

Comment: It can be done correctly (I've done it), but how you define things matters. There's not enough detail here to help you. It's also possible that you don't have enough elements yet - effects of the discretization will show up until you have enough elements, at which point adding more won't change the solution. It's called mesh or grid independence and is an important metric to check.

Comment: Thanks for the keyword, I'll look that up and test it as I go. I do think my wave-speed problem would still exist even if I meshed finely though. What do you mean "how you define things matters"? I'm doing a spiderweb simulation, so one thing I could try is breaking each connecting bit into number of pieces inversely proportional to wave-speed -- is that what you meant? And finally, what more detail should I provide? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Well, we would need to see the exact equations you are solving as well as details of the numerical method for starters. Your edit says that if you double the mesh, it takes 2x the number of iterations -- but, if you are using an explicit temporal scheme, that's totally normal because there is a stability limit based on mesh spacing. Half the spacing means half the time step size, which means 2x the iterations to reach the same physical time. Also, how you define the spring constant matters. If you model your full spring as a bunch of springs in series, the spring constant of the individual...

Comment: ... springs is not the same as the total constant. Nor is it the sum of them. Tht's what I mean by "how you define things matter" and why there isn't enough detail to help you address the problems you have (if there are problems).

Comment: I'm defining the springs  based on a "stiffness" (like 1-d young's modulus), so I am accounting for the series-of-springs problem. If I broke it into two pieces, I would double the spring-constant of each. What you said about halving the mesh and doubling the time makes sense, so thanks for that. The only remaining question is, what if I was simulating two strings under different tensions? As described in my edit, if they were broken down into the same number of pieces, the wavefronts would move at the same speed for both...

Comment: That's undesireable behaviour. Should I calculate number-of-segments from tension? Have something with twice the tension have segments that are twice as long, so the wavefront moves twice as fast? I'm using the first-order symplectic-Euler method for time-stepping. Again, thanks a lot for the interest and help.

Comment: Again, there's not really enough detail to understand what you're doing and where potential hangups may be without the full formulation in the question. [This masters thesis](https://smartech.gatech.edu/handle/1853/53483) uses springs and nodes (with mass) to model solid materials. The temporal integrator descriptions start at page 23 and there are some simple validation cases along the lines of what you are doing. There is a rod-in-tension case and there is a wave transmission through heterogeneous interfaces case. It is also based on Young's Modulus for the spring constants.